# Errors encountered when trying to upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, update-manager, htop

I am actually trying to do something simple which is to install htop. but I get the following error:

```
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-76-generic_3.16.0-76.98~14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-77-generic_3.16.0-77.99~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am able to do a sudo apt-get update but not upgrade.  In the case of the upgrade I get the same error.  It has been a while since this machine was updated so something must be corrupt.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  It seems that my /boot was full.  I found on other forums people resolving this by increasing the size but I took a different, less aggressive approach by cleaning it out with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After this was done I needed to upgrade with:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now that I was able to upgrade I was able to install any package needed.